# "Command not found error" when trying to execute binary file in Jupyter Notebook environment

Tags: python-3.x, bash, path, jupyter-notebook, binaryfiles

I am trying to execute binary files in the Jupyter Notebook cell with the following codes.
They are from the exemplary code which have been proven to work.

```
os.system("hprep96 -M %s.d -d %s -HS %.4f -HR 0 -EQEX"%(model,dfile_out,depth))
!hspec96
!hpulse96 -D -i > file96
!f96tosac -B file96
```

However, following error messages are printed.

```
sh: hprep96: command not found
/usr/bin/sh: hspec96: command not found
/usr/bin/sh: hpulse96: command not found
/usr/bin/sh: f96tosac: command not found
```

My guess for the error is that path to the binary files are not included in the environment for the Jupyter Notebook.

In fact, I updated the paths to these files in the script `~/.bashrc` as follows:

`$ export PATH="/home/msseo/data1/Graduate_Study/01.MomentTensor/CPS_Herrmann/PROGRAMS.330/bin:$PATH"`

Therefore, these binary files are well-executed by just typing them in the terminal. However, I want to execute them from the Jupyter Notebook cell with the commands I wrote previously.

Which line should I add to solve this problem?

Comment: I temporarily solved this problem by moving all binary files in the `/home/msseo/data1/Graduate_Study/01.MomentTensor/CPS_Herrmann/PROGRAMS.330/bin` directory into the current directory where Jupyter Notebook belongs to. However, I would like to know if there is more convenient way to execute the binary files without moving them.

Comment: Assuming that your Python program does not fiddle with the PATH, I guess that the PATH is already incorrect by the time the Python script is invoked. I suggets you do a `printenv PATH` right before calling your Python program, to verify this.

Comment: I don't know the Jupyter environment, but if it is not executed from within an **interactive** bash shell, `changing something in `.bashrc` is pointless.

Comment: @user1934428 Do you mean `print(os.environ['PATH'])`? It seems that it contains the paths that I added in the script `.bashrc`

Comment: Of course, doing it from inside Python also is fine. But if the PATH is OK at this point, the program must be found. BTW, your question does not seem to be related to bash, because your `os.system` call obviously does not run a bash, as you can see from the wording of the error message.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks for the comment. I think I solved the problem using the module `subprocess` instead of `os.system`.